# (When) does $\text{body force}=\text{pressure gradient}=0\neq\text{fluid velocity}\implies0<\text{drag}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> A cylinder with radius $a_1$ moves parallel to its axis with constant positive velocity $U$ inside a stationary coaxial cylinder with radius $a_2(> a_1)$. The region between the cylinders is filled with incompressible fluid. Assume that body forces can be ignored and that the pressure gradient in the direction parallel to the axis is zero. If the velocity in the fluid is in the direction of the axis, determine how it varies in the radial direction.

I'm used to solving problems where (in)viscidity and/or steadiness are given, but here neither is. It would be convenient if I could reason as follows. Does this make sense?
\begin{align}
& \begin{aligned}
\text{Let}&\\
& \vec{F}\text{ be body force per unit mass,} \\
& \vec{F}_D\text{ be drag per unit area,} \\
& \vec{u}\text{ be fluid velocity,} \\
& p\text{ be pressure,} \\
& \mu\text{ be viscosity;}
\end{aligned} \\[1em]
& \text{we have }\vec{F}=\vec{0},\;\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}=0\text{, but }0<u_z \\
\therefore\;&\text{we must have }\vec{F}_D\neq\vec{0}\text{ on the cylinder wall(s)} \tag{$\ast$} \\
\therefore\;&\text{we must have }0<\mu \\
\therefore\;&\text{by the no-slip condition, we must have } (u_z)_{r=a_1}=U\text{, a constant} \\
\therefore\;&\text{we must have }\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t}=0 \\
\therefore\;&\text{by Navier-Stokes, (etc.)}
\end{align}
It's mainly $(\ast)$ I'm wondering about.

Comment: Presumably, the cylinders are infinitely long or at least very long so we are seeking a fully developed solution away from the ends.  Otherwise, it makes no sense to look for steady unidirectional flow -- where only one component of velocity $u_z$ is non-zero and depends only on the radial coordinate $r$.  I would also assume that there is viscosity because there would be only a trivial solution for inviscid unidirectional flow without an imposed pressure gradient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For steady, unidirectional axial flow driven by the motion of the inner cylinder and without an imposed axial pressure gradient, the Navier-Stokes equations -- expressed in terms of cylindrical coordinates -- reduce to

$$\frac{\mu}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} \right) = 0$$

Integrating twice, we get the general solution

$$u_z = A \log r +B,$$

where $A$ and $B$ are integration constants.  The usual no-slip boundary conditions imposed at the inner and outer cylinder surfaces are sufficient to obtain a unique solution.  These are

$$\left. u_z\right|_{r=a_1} = U, \quad\left. u_z\right|_{r=a_2} = 0,$$

yielding the solution

$$A = \frac{U}{\log \cfrac{a_1}{a_2}}, \quad B= -\frac{U\log a_2}{\log \cfrac{a_1}{a_2}}$$

Hence,

$$u_z = U \frac{\log \frac{r}{a_2}}{\log \frac{a_1}{a_2}}$$

---

What assumptions lead to this solution? First, we are given that there are no body forces, the pressure gradient parallel to the axis is zero, and the fluid velocity has only a non-zero axial component $u_z$.

With $u_r = u_\theta = 0$ as assumed, the continuity equation $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$ reduces to $\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z } = 0$. At this stage we can not rule out dependence in the angular direction, and we have $u_z = u_z(r,\theta)$.

The axial component of the Navier-Stokes equations then reduces to

$$\rho \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t} = \frac{\mu}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{\mu}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u_z}{\partial \theta^2},$$

and the angular component reduces to

$$-\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta} + \frac{2\mu}{r^2} \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial \theta}= 0$$

With no angular pressure gradient, it follows that $\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial \theta} = 0$ and $u_z = u_z(r)$ -- leading to the above solution in steady state.

If you do not make the steady-state assumption, then a solution to the parabolic eqution for $u_z(r,t)$ requires that you impose an initial condition such as an impulsive start at $t = 0+$.

Comment: Would you agree with the following? \begin{align}&\text{inviscid solution trivial}\\\implies&\text{assume viscidity}\\\implies&u_z=u_z(r)\text{ (independent of $\theta,t$)}\\\implies&\text{Navier Stokes, as you wrote.}\end{align}

Comment: The Navier-Stokes equations can admit a multiplicity of solutions in a given configuration all the way to fully turbulent flow.  The point here is we looking for the simplest solution that is supported by the assumptions. In practice we can confirm this is a relevant solution empirically. We would  get an unsteady flow by setting the inner cylinder in motion impulsively. The transient velocity field would decay eventually by viscous effects and settle down to the steady flow solved for here. By symmetry there should be no angular dependence. Also what could drive an angular component?

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do is be clear on what assumptions I can or must make in what context. Is the trivial inviscid solution $u_z=$ constant (independent of $r,\theta,z,t$)? If I do NS with $\mu=0$ I get $\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t}=0$, but that only gets us $u_z=u_z(r,\theta)$ (with $z$-independence from no-divergence). Re your answer, I think you've expanded my "etc.", which is not un-useful, but I'm mainly trying to understand the part before that. Re "what could drive an angular component", couldn't there have been one initially, not needing further drive because of inviscidity?

Comment: I have derived the simplest solution of the Navier-Stokes equations that applies to this geometry.  Plugging in to the full equations you can verify that it is a valid solution. Is this the only possible solution. No. In the physical world, this basic flow will become unstable as the cylinder speed (and Reynolds number increase) and there will ensue a series of bifurcations to more complex flows with other non-zero velocity components and dependence on axial and angular coordinates as well as time -- leading to turbulence.

Comment: These develop even without unsteady motion of the inner cylinder in multiple directions.  So it seems you want to know what the minimum set of assumptions is to generate this solution - correct.  Start with the full Navier-Stokes equations and the continuity equation and see how the terms drop out,

Comment: I assumed no turbulence for the non-physical reason that we haven't yet covered turbulence in the course. I guess it would have been useful if I'd thought to point that out. So that's another implicit assumption. If you have the patience to go a little further: starting with the full NS equations and the continuity equation is what I (think I) did, and I got \begin{align}&\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}=0,\\&\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}=0,\\&\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t}=\frac{\mu}{\rho}\nabla^2u_z.\end{align} I think I'm happy with the case $\mu\neq0$, using the reasoning above.

Comment: I'm adding to the answer right now with a complete derivation.

Comment: OK, thanks. If you could say something about the trivial case $\mu=0$, and how that gets us further than $u_z=u_z(r,\theta)$, that would be appreciated.

Comment: We get from $u_z = u_z(r,\theta)$ to $u_z = u_z(r)$ by assuming no angular pressure gradient as I showed.

Comment: We seem to have a disagreement on the angular component. I get $$\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial t}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla u_\theta=0=-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial p}{\partial\theta}=(\nabla p)_\theta+\mu\nabla^2u_\theta.$$ Doesn't your $\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial\theta}$ belong in the axial equation? If not, I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations under Cylindrical Coordinates there is a term $(2\mu/r^2)\partial_{\varphi}u_z$ in the $\varphi-$momentum equation.

Comment: In transforming from Cartesian to (curvillinear) cylindrical  coordiates you don't just get $\mu \nabla^2 u_\theta$ for the viscous term. See also https://demichie.github.io/NS_cylindrical/

Comment: I can't seem to see it in the [equation](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b5866f05f6fb2d214f48908c2f2e2c37197777fe) I'm looking at. My course notes have a $\mu\nabla\cdot\vec{u}$ term for non-Newtonian fluids, which is left out as we don't study them, but I would still have expected any term looking like $\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial_\theta}$ to be in the axial equation. There seems to be something I'm missing. I might say at this point that, although I haven't yet fully understood what I've been trying to, I appreciate the amount of time you've taken to help.

Comment: Look closely at the right side of Eq. 22 in the second link I posted above. It is the second to last term just before $g_\theta$.

Comment: I see it. I guess I'd better work through that derivation. Thanks for all your help.